# Want to display the first character of word in django templates

Tags: python, css, django, django-templates

I want to display first character of user in django templates.
I want to make a image of user first character like caption or avatar

like this https://meta.discourse.org/t/switch-from-gravatar-to-html-css-letters-for-no-avatar-users/15336

```
<p>{{postone.user}}</p>
```

so i will get result like any name "Gaurav" or "Amit" but i just want first letter of them like "G" or "A"
So i can display it like image of first letter.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Solution with using templates tags(but for me the answer from @Kasra  more preferable):

First letter:

```
{{ postone.user|make_list|first }}
```

Word without first:

```
{{ postone.user|make_list|slice:'1:'|join:'' }}
```

Comment: The problem is you can no longer use the filter "richtext" on the item after the join. How can i pick the first letter and still apply richtext.

Answer (score 27):

try
`<p>{{ postone.user.first_name.0 }}</p>`